# Help installing Ubuntu 14 LTS on Pcduino3

Tags: support

i do not know how to get Ubuntu 14 l.t.s. on my pcduino3b, need help,
i currently run Ubuntu, but is the default version for this device.
what kernel and ISO do i need.
Do not know what source to get these from otherwise i would have done this.

Comment: what sh file do i use, and how can this be done while booting of sd

Answer (score 0):

The ISO comes with the Linux Kernel and some software. The ISO you need depends on the architecture i.e. i386 or am64.

14.04 uses kernel 3.13 but 4.0 (and newer) have been released somewhat recently.

[Ubuntu ISO's](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)